# observable forkjoin never executes the observable angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm trying to execute multiple XHR request (inside `getImages` function), each wrapped in an observable (inside `getImage` function), using `forkJoin`. However, none of the requests are executed i.e. `observer.next()` is never executed. I have tried using `zip` instead of `forkJoin` but that doesn't work either. I'm making sure that I can `complete` on all the observables that I'm creating.

```
getImages(urls: string[]) {
    Observable.forkJoin(...urls.map(url => {return this.getImage(url)}))
           .subscribe(
               (result) => {console.log(result)}, 
               (err) => {console.log(err)},
               () => {});
}

private getImage(url: string): Observable<string> {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return Observable.create((observer => {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    observer.next(xhr.response);
                } else {
                    observer.error(xhr.response);
                }
                observer.complete();
            }
        }
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar enough with XMLHttpRequest, but from your diagnosis and the samples i've seen of its usage, i imagine that your not reaching readyState of 4 (DONE) because you haven't called xhr.send().

From the example listed @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

So I imagine you might want to amend your code to:

```
return Observable.create((observer => {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                observer.next(xhr.response);
            } else {
                observer.error(xhr.response);
            }
            observer.complete();
        }
    }
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}))
```